# Shipping method based on ZipCodes In Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, shipping-methods, zipcode

I want to show shipping method based on ZipCodes.

Like if zipcode isn't match with my list than shipping method doesn't need to show.

How can i achieve that ?

Comment: have u tried so far?

Comment: @AmitBera, I am confused is it really possible or not ?
But thinking about to create sample module and check with in_array().

Comment: Yes, it possible..Are want to feature of existing  shipping method?

Comment: I have developed custom module when order placed through observer it will call API and send order details, but that shipping carrier have some restricted to some zip code. So whenever checkout is processing need to validate their zip codes with entered by customer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set shipping method based on Zip/Post code by Magento-2 default table rates shipping method.[image]

You can add you Zip/Postal code which you want to apply shipping rates, shipping rates apply based on define in this table.

You can read complete guide here : [Table Rate Shipping](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/shipping/shipping-table-rate.html)

Comment: Thanks for responding but this also not work.

Comment: What is issue with this?

Comment: it will work based on weigh or destinationt, but i need to disable whole shipping method, if entered zip code isn't present in my list.